# How to force npm to flatten dependencies?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-aot

I have a project in which several frontends sharing a common lib.

The module dependencies of those projects are managed by npm.

So, in the package.json of each of those projects I have :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "mylib": "file:../<...path...>/mylib",
    ...other deps...
  },
```

I use "mylib" for two purposes :

- share some classes ;
- share common dependencies (mostly, angular)

Until now, I was using npm 3.3.12 and after running `npm install`, the angular dependencies of mylib where right under the node_modules directory of my top level projects.

So, I had for instance

```
node_modules
    @angular
        core
        common
        ....
    mylib
```

Now, with npm 5.4.2, I have :

```
node_modules
    mylib
        node_modules
            @angular
                core
                common
```

This causes a lot of problems in my build process.It requires additional configuration of typescript, by adding directives such as :

```
"baseUrl": "",
"paths": {
    "@angular/common": ["node_modules/mylib/node_modules/@angular/common/"],
    "@angular/core": ["node_modules/mylib/node_modules/@angular/core/"],
    "@angular/compiler": ["node_modules/mylib/node_modules/@angular/compiler/"],
    "@angular/compiler-cli": ["node_modules/mylib/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/"],
    "@angular/forms": ["node_modules/mylib/node_modules/@angular/forms/"],
    "@angular/http": ["node_modules/mylib/node_modules/@angular/http/"],
    "@angular/platform-browser": ["node_modules/mylib/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/"],
    "@angular/platform-browser/animations": ["node_modules/mylib/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/"],
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": ["node_modules/mylib/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/"],
    "@angular/router": ["node_modules/mylib/node_modules/@angular/router/"],
    "primeng/primeng": ["node_modules/mylib/node_modules/primeng/primeng"],
    "rxjs/Rx": ["node_modules/mylib/node_modules/rxjs/Rx"]
    }
```

in tsconfig.json

It becomes really annoying when you have to do similar configurations for AOT, rollup, etc...

I tried to use npm dedupe do simplify this. As the projects have a lot of dependencies, it takes over 10mn for just one of them :

```
npm dedupe
...
...
removed 824 packages and moved 1020 packages in 623.196s
```

Is there a standard, *efficient* way to have the same kind of dependencies flattening as before ? npm dedupe does the job, but takes so much time that it is not an acceptable alternative.

Comment: Have you tried add all of those dependencies as peerDependencies within myLib?

Comment: I do not get how it would help me. I want to specify the dep in myLib. With peerDependencies, I would have to add those deps in my top level projects, no ? And I have stuff dependending on those dependencies in "myLib"...

Comment: Take a look at https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/ I think in your case you want these dependencies in both myLib as a peerDependency and in your other projects

Comment: Try switching to `yarn` instead. Install it then remove your `node_modules` folder and do `yarn install --flat`. Or just `yarn install` should still do the dedupe.

Comment: @Duncan : yarn install (without --flat) did the job. You made my day. Propose this as an answer so that I can credit you.

Comment: Everest : no, I do not want to have to repeat them in the top level projects.

Comment: `npm dedupe` was immensely helpful for me to find here, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an alternative to `npm` you might want to switch to using `yarn`. That should dedupe modules by default. Start by removing your existing `node_modules` folder then just do `yarn install`.

You can also force `yarn` to do a flat install (`yarn install --flat`), but in this case it may be sufficient just to do the plain install.

Add the `yarn.lock` file to version control and any other checkout will then be locked down to the same module versions (unless they do `yarn upgrade`).

Comment: Dealing with local dependencies, with dev team members using a variety of OS's, yarn was the only reliable solution to this issue.